# GMail API Oauth Zend framework token refresh php

Tags: php, oauth, imap, token, google-oauth

i am in the situation that i have to use the zend framework along with oauth 2 for gmail.
all works fine and i get the messages and login just fine, my problem is that the token expire too fast.

am i able to set it so it will never expire or how should i implement a refresh token to the framework ? i use standard code when it comes to login.

what i basically need is an access-token that does not expire or a guide for how to implement a refresh token and how to use it in a program.

any help is appreciated.
thank you.

this is the login page.

```
include("../classes/Google/Client.php");


$client_id = "hidden";
$client_secret = "hidden";
$redirect_uri = "hidden";

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");
$client->addScope("https://mail.google.com/");

$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();


echo "<a href=".$authUrl.">Login</a>";
```

this is the callback

```
$client_id = "hidden";
$client_secret = "hidden";
$redirect_uri = "hidden";

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);


  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();



  $oauth2 = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
  $user = $oauth2->userinfo->get();
  $_SESSION['email'] = $user;


  $redirect = 'hidden';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

i know the code is not great, but i wonder if i should get a refresh token along with the access token ?

Comment: Access tokens are only good for 1 hour there is nothing you can do to change that.  You need to use the Refresh token to get a new access token before it expires.   Are you using the Google PHP client lib? Can you post the code you are currently using to get authentication?

Comment: of course.... i will post it in a second :)

Comment: anyone with an idea on how i should use the refresh-token ?

Comment: I haven't had time to test it. but this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23880928/use-oauth-refresh-token-to-obtain-new-access-token-google-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if someone are interested i have done like this to fix it... now it works like it should.

this method is called every time i need to do something with the mails (if the access token is not valid then you will not have access, so this is to make sure access is always there.)

```
public function checktokenexpiry()
    {
    global $google_client; // this is global as we use it in our webservice.
    session_start();
    $time_created = json_decode($_SESSION['access_token']);

    $t=time();
    $timediff=$t-$time_created->created;

    if($timediff>3500) // 3500 as i want to have a little time to connect if it is just about to need refreshing. 
    {
        $user = json_decode($_COOKIE['user']);
        $usermail = $user->email;
        $refreshtoken = $this->model->getRefreshToken($usermail);
        $refreshtoken = $refreshtoken[0]['google_refresh_token'];

        $google_client->refreshToken($refreshtoken);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $google_client->getAccessToken();   
    }   
    }
```