# Use OAuth Refresh Token to Obtain New Access Token - Google API

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

My app is simple, it connects to the Google+ API to authenticate the user, and if successful, it retrieves the user's **email** and then performs a series of operations on a given database based on the email retrieved.

My main issue is that every hour, my access token expires, and I seem not to know how to "refresh" it. I get the following error, which I imagine is expected:

```
The OAuth 2.0 access token has expired, and a refresh token is not available.
```

I am currently storing the access token on a database, and I can therefore retrieve if needed. My only question is how do I use that token to gain a new one?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Whoa, it took me significantly longer to figure this out, and the answers out there seemed quite incomplete to me.

Before we start please keep in mind that this answer assumes you are using the latest [Google API PHP Library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client), as of *May 26th of 2014*.

1 - Make sure the access type your app requests is `offline`. A `refresh_token` is **not provided** otherwise. From Google: *This field is only present if access_type=offline is included in the authorization code request.*

```
$gClient->setAccessType('offline');
```

2 - Upon the first authorization, persist the provided `refresh_token` for further access. This can be done via **cookies**, **database**, etc. I chose to store in on a database:

```
$tokens = json_decode($gClient->getAccessToken()); /* Get a JSON object */
setRefreshToken($con, $tokens->refresh_token /* Retrieve form JSON object */);
```

3 - Check if the `AccessToken` has expired, and request a refreshed token from Google if such is the case.

```
if ($gClient->isAccessTokenExpired()) {    
  $refreshToken = getRefreshToken($con, $email); 
  $gClient->refreshToken($refreshToken);
}
```

Where `getRefreshToken` is retrieving the previously stored `refresh_token` from our database, and then we pass that value to the Client's `refreshToken` method.

**Quick Note:** It's key to remember that if you had previously authorized your app, you probably won't see a `refresh_token` on the response, since it is only provided the first time we call `authenticate`. Therefore, you can either go to https://www.google.com/settings/security and **Revoke Access** to your app or you can add the following line when creating the Client object:

```
$gClient->setApprovalPrompt('force');
```

From Google: *If the value is force, then the user sees a consent page even if they previously gave consent to your application for a given set of scopes.* Which in turn ensures that a `refresh_token` is provided on each authorization.

Full Sample Here: http://pastebin.com/jA9sBNTk

Comment: Ok I know thank you comments are frowned upon by stack but.  Thanks. been playing with this on and off for a week. :)

Comment: @daniel_c05 Can you help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870439/how-to-use-refresh-token-to-get-authorized-in-background-and-getting-access-toke